# (sqlite3 module for node.js) Fetchall statement?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm currently in the process of translating a python program into node.js, and using sqlite3 modules for both of them. My python code goes like this:

```
    users_db = sqlite3.connect(drive()+'\\Recovered\\NewProgramVersions\\users_db.db')
    c=users_db.cursor()

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE useremail=?",(email,))
    rows = c.fetchall()

    if rows != []: #if the returned rows are NOT empty
        errorlbl.config(text="Email already in use!") #...then print an error message
        x=1
```

What important to me is running lines 4 and 5. Selecting the data, and putting it into an array called "rows".
So far in my JS file I have:

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database('users_db.db');
var stmt = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE useremail=?");
stmt.run(email);

var rows = db.all(stmt);
```

But I think this is the wrong syntax, and can't find anywhere on Google how to do this exactly.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

My solution involved following the syntax included in the documentation. After experimenting I found that this works:

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database('users_db.db');

db.all("SELECT * FROM users WHERE useremail=?", email, function(err, rows){

    if (rows != "undefined"){
        res.send("Email already exists!");
        return false; //returns false
    }else{
        return true; //if all is okay, return true
    }
})
```